# null return by getElementById method in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

null return by getElementById method in JavaScript

```
<html>
<head>

<title>test_elementObject</title>

<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
<!--
        var input1 = document.getElementById ( "input1" );
        input1.value = "sample text"
//-->
</script>


</head>

<body>

<input id = "input1" type = "text" value = "" />

</body>
</html>
```

I'm new in JavaScript 
why the script cause error: "input1 is null"?

Comment: You ought to remove the spaces around your `=`, for clean valid html, though it isn't the source of your error  `<input id='input1' type='text' value='' />`

Comment: the `<!--` and `-->` inside the `<script>` tag is outdated, you does not have to do this anymore.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It happened because this code is executed before the body content is loaded. Try this code:

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
<!--
window.onload = function(){
    var input1 = document.getElementById ( "input1" );
    input1.value = "sample text"
}
//-->
</script>
```

This command makes the code execute only when all the page content is loaded
And remember that `<!--` and `//-->` are outdated, due to javascript compatibility on all recent browsers

Answer (score 2):

move the script element below the input element. JavaScript is an *Event Driven* Language and parsed/executed top down.

```
<title>test_elementObject</title>

</head>
<body>
    <input id = "input1" type = "text" value = "" />
</body>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
<!--
    var input1 = document.getElementById ( "input1" );
    input1.value = "sample text"
//-->
</script>
</html>
```

---

Or, you could properly use events:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function(e){
    var input1 = document.getElementById ( "input1" );
    input1.value = "sample text"
}, false);
```

Answer (score 2):

That's because the DOM is not ready when you select the input field. You could either move the script after the markup.

```
<html>
<head>    
<title>test_elementObject</title>               
</head>

<body>

<input id = "input1" type = "text" value = "" />
 <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">   
        var input1 = document.getElementById ( "input1" );
        input1.value = "sample text"   
</script>
</body>
```

or hook up to the window.onload function, this will ensure the document has been parsed and the DOM is ready.

```
window.onload = function(){
    var input1 = document.getElementById ( "input1" );
    input1.value = "sample text"
}
```

PS you don't need the comments `<!--` in the script tags anymore, unless your users are using the mosaic browser or older IE browsers 1 and 2, this technique is outdated.