# javascript - Why doesn't innerHTML replacing run?

Tags: javascript, web

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<script>
document.write("TEST1")
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML="TEST2"
document.write("TEST3")
</script>
</head>

<body>
<p id="demo">TO_BE_REPLACED</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the output:
    TEST1

```
TO_BE_REPLACED
```

It seems the javascript executing stopped at `document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML="TEST2"`. Why doesn't it execute?

Comment: See this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5704924/executing-javascript-in-the-head-getelementbyid-returns-null , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8864776/getelementbyid-and-null-why , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5371047/getelementbyid-returns-null-even-though-the-element-exists or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10839271/null-return-by-getelementbyid-method-in-javascript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the script is being run, `<p id="demo">` *does not exist yet*. Therefore, `document.getElementById('demo')` is returning `null`, which then triggers an error when you try to assign `null.innerHTML = "TEST2"`

This error stops all execution, so you never get to see the final `TEST3`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to enclose your script in a function that will be called when the window loads (using "window.onload" event).

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<script>
    function replaceDemoText()
    {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML="TEST2";
    }
    window.onload = replaceDemoText;
</script>
</head>

<body>
<p id="demo">TO_BE_REPLACED</p>
</body>
</html>
```